# Android studio Flutter Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I WAS RUNNING MY CODE ON THE EMULATOR AND THEN THE BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

When you've specified a version `XX` of `compileSdkVersion` (file that you can find under `../adroid/app/build.gradle`) that version `XX` **must be present** on the machine which compile your project (in your case your PC).

You can download that version by SDK Manager on Tab "SDK Tools" (tick the exact version you've specified in your `build.gradle` file)

Image below may call your memory of IDE usage :).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello Elimimian Osemaoje,

Please follow the following steps.

Step 1: Open Preferences or Settings in Android studio. Select Android SDK options and Install Android API 31 as selected below.

https://prnt.sc/TCjn0jTfgsIY

There's a problem with CompileSdkVersion as you have to change it from 'android-P' to 31.

compileSdkVersion 31 And Build project. That's it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Image you've attached shows SDK Platform. SDK platform provides Platform/Framework/A Set Of CODE you can use when you write code for Android Java/Kotlin and it is NOT SDK Building Tools which is the problem that doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes @G3nt_M3caj we are missing SDK tools screenshot in our answer so you also need to install 33.0.1 which is located in android SDK build-tools 34-rc1. Please check this screenshot https://prnt.sc/XS7Jot_kb8JJ for more details.